# php script in html

Tags: php, html, mysql

i am trying to display mysql data in html

table format is

table name:: App

```
   appid |    app    | version |     date     |      apk file   |
   1        sample     1.0.0      2012-10-12         sample.apk
```

//mysql query is

```
   <?php
    $query="SELECT * FROM `App` where appid=1";
    $res=mysql_query($query);
    $row=mysql_fetch_row($res);
    $app=$row[1];
    $vesion=$row[2];
    $date1=date('M j,Y',strtotime($row[3]));
 ?>
```

//html code is given below

```
 <html>
     <body>
      <div style="text-align:left"><p>App:<b><? $app.' '.$vesion ?></b></p></div>
      <div style="text-align:left"><p>Date Uploaded: <b><? $date1 ?></b></p></div>
      <ol class="instructions">
         <li>Click <a href="http://localhost/downloads/$row[4]">Here</a> todownload.
 <br></li>

     </ol>
     </body>
     </html>
<?php 

?>
```

but do not getting mysql data in html file

any one help me for correct solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok so two things may be happening here.

1. You need to wrap any PHP code with the opening and closing PHP tags -  `<?php  ?>`. This includes single variables like you did with `row[4]`. You'll also need to echo out the variable -

   `<a href="http://localhost/downloads/<?php echo $row[4]; ?>">Here</a>`
2. Make sure you HTML file has the `.php` file extension. Other wise the server will simply not parse the file as PHP and your code will not be executed as PHP but rather as plain text. You can setup your server to parse PHP even in HTML files - this is done sometimes for security measures as to not let users know what technologies are being used on the server (but I'm not sure if that's what you are going for here).

Answer (score 4):

You can print the value of the variables out like so:

```
<div style="text-align:left"><p>App:<b><? echo $app . ' ' . $vesion ?></b></p></div>
```

Comment: Need to note here the settings related to the [short_open_tag](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag). Not all setups support this by default.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah. You missed the `echo`
And try this:

```
<?php
$query="SELECT * FROM `App` where appid=1";
$res=mysql_query($query);
$row=mysql_fetch_array($res);
$app=$row['app'];
$vesion=$row['version'];
?>
<a href="http://localhost/downloads/<?=$row['apk file']?>">Here</a>
```

Use var_dump to test what you get from DB.